# Any reason not to add js files using php include?

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have 5 javascript files that need to be loaded on every page of a website, is there any reason not to add those js files to an external html document and load the list of files dynamically using a php include?

**What I've done historically:**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Whatever Content -->

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="pathto/file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="pathto/file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="pathto/file3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="pathto/file4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="pathto/file5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

**Is there any reason not to do it this way?**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Whatever Content -->

    <?php include_once "pathto/scripts.html" ?>

</body>
```

**Where scripts.html looks like:**

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="pathto/file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pathto/file2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pathto/file3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pathto/file4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="pathto/file5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Obviously it works. I'm just double checking that for basic web applications, that this is a perfectly acceptable (or preferred) way to load those scripts and that it isn't causing unnecessary server requests/load time issues.

**Just to Clarify:**

I often have a small handful of core javascript files that I load externally.  I'm asking if it makes sense to take that list of files and load it dynamically using a php include.  That way, if I need to add a new js file to each page, I'm not having to go in and edit each page separately.

Thanks in advance for not flaming the rookie.  I did search first and wasn't finding a definitive answer.

Comment: who told you that you have to do this ?

Comment: ??  Nobody.  That's why I'm asking.  I've commonly used the includes for various, reusable html snippets.  Just looking to confirm there's no issue with using the same method for adding the core js files that would be the same across multiple pages.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="pathto/scripts.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks bud.  I understand how to add a js file to the bottom of the page.  What I'm asking is if I have multiple js files that will be used on every page, is there any reason not to create a separate html file with those scripts and then load them to each page using a php include?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the answers probably don't understand what are you asking.
You are not including javascript with php include, you are including part of your html code that contains links to your js files.

Your second solution (with inlcude inside index.php file and scripts.html) is absolutely ok. Especially if you have multiple templates where you include scripts.html.

If you use your first (*historic*) solution on multiple pages and you want to remove one js file, it will cost you more work to edit these files. It is also more prone to errors, you can easily forget to edit one of your templates.

Don't be afraid to use the new technique. Browser output will be the same as in the first, static file and all browsers will cache js files the same way.

Answer (score 0):

What you *should* do is put each JS file into a separate file that you load from HTML:

```
<script src="pathto/script1.js"></script>
<script src="pathto/script2.js"></script>
```

This way, the browser can cache the Javascript files. If the same file is used in multiple pages, it will only have to be downloaded once, not included as part of every page.

Comment: So if I load my script list using a php include, it will not cache the js files?

Comment: Of course not. The browser doesn't know what PHP is doing on the server, it just gets the response as one big file.

Comment: Remember, PHP runs on the server, not the client.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was hoping since the output source would include the js files that they'd still get cached.  So if someone needs to add a new script across multiple pages in a primarily static site, is there a better solutioni than copy and pasting or using template functionality on whatever text editor is being used?

Comment: Caching is done by URL. The browser never sees the URL of the JS files, they're just part of the whole HTML file.

Comment: I just noticed the edit to your question. If that's what you want, you certainly can put all those script tags in a single file and include it in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to include any external js file you should use
`<script src="pathto/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. this is not a right to link any js file and you should defined it inside the head or at the last of the body and by the order of dependencies of the files.

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="your_link" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```